# Slow query log: where should be configured on mariadb o a debian 12?

Tags: debian, logs, mariadb

If I do

```
show global variables like "%slow%"
```

I get these results

[image]

But I am not able to find where these values are set up.

I tried to find, litterally

```
cd /etc/mysql
grep slow -R -n
```

And obtained totally different results

```
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:21:# Broken reverse DNS slows down connections considerably and name resolve is
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:63:# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:64:#log_slow_query_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:65:#log_slow_query_time    = 10
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:66:#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan,explain
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:68:#log_slow_min_examined_row_limit = 1000
conf.d/mysql.cnf:3:log_slow_query                   = on
conf.d/mysql.cnf:4:log_slow_query_file              = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
conf.d/mysql.cnf:5:log_slow_query_time              = 1.0
conf.d/mysql.cnf:6:log_slow_verbosity               = query_plan,explain
conf.d/mysql.cnf:7:log_slow_min_examined_row_limit  = 10
```

Where damn the "debian-slow.log" file is set up ?
Where and how should I override these configs ?
Why my conf.d/mysql.cnf file is totally ignored?